# cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type WindowsPath not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using `cx_Oracle` to insert binary files from a directory as BLOB in a column of a table.

So, I am intended to use the `PATH` module of python3 and then insert the binary file by fetching the file using `WindowsPath`. Here's the example:-

```
import sys
import cx_Oracle

from pathlib import Path

username = 'EWORDPR'
password = 'EWORDPR'
databaseName = "10.11.201.161:1521/ORCL"

connection = cx_Oracle.connect (username,password,databaseName) # Connection Established

cursor=connection.cursor()

my_file = Path("22 Apr 2018.txt")
print("File exists:",my_file.is_file()) #File Exists: True

rows = [ ('01787440110', 'Rakin','22-04-2017', my_file )]
cursor.executemany('insert into CHAT_HISTORY(MOBILE_NUMBER,USER_NAME,CHAT_DATE,USER_TRANSCRIPTS) values (:1, :2, :3, :4)', rows)

connection.commit()

cursor.close()

connection.close()
```

Then, I am getting the following errors:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:/Python with ORACLE/orapy.py", line 53, in 
>       print(cursor.executemany('insert into CHAT_HISTORY(MOBILE_NUMBER,USER_NAME,CHAT_DATE,USER_TRANSCRIPTS) values (:1, :2, :3, :4)', rows))
>   cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type WindowsPath not supported.

Is there any way to export binary files from a directory and then directly insert the file in as BLOB using cx_Oracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since files can contain any type of data you have to open and read the contents yourself. This can be done easily enough using the following:

```
rows = [ ('01787440110', 'Rakin','22-04-2017', my_file.open("rb").read() )]
```

This will work effectively for files that readily fit in memory and for those types of files this is the most efficient way to do that. For very large files you will need to use a LOB locator and stream the data instead.